# Difference between integral and float point arithmetic in C#?

Tags: c#

What is difference between integral and float point arithmetic in C#?

I tried looking online and reading articles but it was not answering the question directly.

Comment: What do you mean by integral ?

Comment: Here is a good C# resource to keep on hand from [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/arithmetic-operators) to explain Integer vs Floating-Point behavior of mathematical operators. Look through and you will find clear examples for each operator that has different expected behavior depending on variable type. (For example: [Division](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/arithmetic-operators))

Comment: The difference is just how the number is represented.  Integral number are integers like 1,2,3,... where addition subtraction and multiplication results into another integer.  Division you can get fractions.  Floating Point numbers are in scientific notation 123.456E78 and allow for fractions and exponents which gives a much larger range of numbers.  Floating point number are not always precise like 1/3 = .33333333333333333333

Comment: The same as in any other typed language. Integers can not represent decimal numbers. While Floats are notoriously inprecise: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PZRI1IfStY0 Weakly typed langauges can just switch between the types or even use weird stuff like storing them as Strings, BigInts or whatever they see fit. But in C# the value range you define during declaration is exactly the value range you get.

Comment: This is a very difficult question to answer because there are *a great many* differences. ints have no "infinity", doubles do. ints overflow by wrapping, doubles do not. int addition is exact, double addition can be inexact. ints have fixed precision; doubles can use higher precision if enregistered. I could probably list several dozen differences off the top of my head. **Ask a more specific question**.

Comment: @AliAlp: An Integral type is a type used for integers.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/integral-types-table for a list of integral types.

Answer (score 2):

Several arithmetic operators are affected by integer vs floating point logic. The most common one that trips people up is the [divisor operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/arithmetic-operators#division-operator-)

> **Integer division**
>
> For the operands of integer types, the result of the / operator is of an integer type and equals the quotient of the two operands rounded towards zero:
>
> **Floating-point division**
>
> For the float, double, and decimal types, the result of the / operator is the quotient of the two operands:

an example is shown below.

```cs
var intResult = 5/2; //result is 2, not 2.5
var doubleResult = 5/2.0; //result is 2.5
```

Other items affected by integer vs floating point logic are the following

[remainder operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/arithmetic-operators#remainder-operator-)

> **Integer remainder**
>
> For the operands of integer types, the result of a % b is the value produced by a - (a / b) * b. The sign of the non-zero remainder is the same as that of the first operand...
>
> **Floating-point remainder**
>
> For the float and double operands, the result of x % y for the finite x and y is the value z such that
>
> - The sign of z, if non-zero, is the same as the sign of x.
> - The absolute value of z is the value produced by |x| - n * |y| where n is the largest possible integer that is less than or equal to |x| / |y| and |x| and |y| are the absolute values of x and y, respectively.

The remainder operator just produces a remainder for both integer and floating point operations. The description for a floating point remainder just has to be more descriptive since it is operating on floating point values. Examples are shown below

```cs
Console.WriteLine(5 % 4);   // output: 1
Console.WriteLine(5 % -4);  // output: 1
Console.WriteLine(-5 % 4);  // output: -1
Console.WriteLine(-5 % -4); // output: -1
Console.WriteLine(-5.2f % 2.0f); // output: -1.2
Console.WriteLine(5.9 % 3.1);    // output: 2.8
Console.WriteLine(5.9m % 3.1m);  // output: 2.8
```

Another example just to show that integer remainders and float remainders are the same. Only difference is one returns an int and the other returns a double.

```cs
Console.WriteLine(5.0 % 4.0);    // output: 1.0
```

[arithmetic overflow and divide by zero](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/arithmetic-operators#arithmetic-overflow-and-division-by-zero)

> **Integer arithmetic overflow**
>
> Integer division by zero always throws a `DivideByZeroException`.
>
> In case of integer arithmetic overflow, an overflow checking context, which can be checked or unchecked, controls the resulting behavior:
>
> - In a checked context, if overflow happens in a constant expression, a compile-time error occurs. Otherwise, when the operation is performed at run time, an `OverflowException` is thrown.
> - In an unchecked context, the result is truncated by discarding any high-order bits that don't fit in the destination type.
>     Along with the checked and unchecked statements, you can use the checked and unchecked operators to control the overflow checking context, in which an expression is evaluated:

```cs
int a = int.MaxValue;
int b = 3;

Console.WriteLine(unchecked(a + b));  // output: -2147483646
try
{
    int d = checked(a + b);
}
catch(OverflowException)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Overflow occured when adding {a} to {b}.");
}
```

> **Floating-point arithmetic overflow**
>
> Arithmetic operations with the `float` and `double` types never throw an exception. The result of arithmetic operations with those types can be one of special values that represent infinity and not-a-number:

```cs
double a = 1.0 / 0.0;
Console.WriteLine(a);                    // output: Infinity
Console.WriteLine(double.IsInfinity(a)); // output: True

Console.WriteLine(double.MaxValue + double.MaxValue); // output: Infinity

double b = 0.0 / 0.0;
Console.WriteLine(b);                // output: NaN
Console.WriteLine(double.IsNaN(b));  // output: True
```

Basically, `int`s will throw overflow exceptions depending on if you are checking for overflow or not and will always throw divide by zero exceptions. Floating point values will not overflow, but instead take on a special value of infinity, or in some cases not a number (NaN)

These differences exist for almost every programming language, but the specifics may be handled differently.

Comment: Your answer could be even greater if you could [provide context to all the links](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) _Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline._